# Gamma and Gamma convolutions?

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

I'm trying to do a convolution between two parameters Gamma distribution.
The two distributions are Gamma~($\alpha=3, \theta=1500$) and Gamma~($\alpha=3, \theta=1400$).

Since both are non-negative, I believe the joint pdf is given by this equation: $$f(z)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{(z-y)^2}{1500^3\cdot \Gamma(3)}e^{-\frac{z-y}{1500}}\cdot \frac{(y)^2}{1400^3\cdot \Gamma(3)}e^{-\frac{y}{1400}}\,dy$$
Then i solve the integral to get the joint pdf : $\frac{(z^2-126000z+5292000000)e^{-\frac{z}{1500}}}{2000000}$, the problem is when i integrate this joint pdf from 0 to $\infty$, the result is not 1, instead of 3830625.

Can i multiply $\frac{1}{3830625}$ with the joint pdf?  So when i integrate it from $0$ to $\infty$ it will become 1 and therefore it fulfills the PDF characteristics? If it is ok, what is the explanation?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

The gamma distribution is defined for $x>0$ or $y>0$.

$x=z-y>0\Rightarrow y<z$

Thus your integral is $$f_{X+Y}(z)=\int_0^z f(z-y)\cdot f(y) \, dy$$